# Is there a GUI Real-Time previewer for Python (PyCharm)?

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, frontend

I'm new here on Stack and I'm also new to GUI programming. I'm working on a software engineering project for a university exam and I was wondering if there was a sort of plugin for PyCharm for previewing the widget I'm coding while I write. I'm asking because I'm 100% sure I saw some reels on ig where people were front-end developing while having a real-time preview tab on the right.
Sorry if I asked something stupid, I just never did stuff like that before (I'm using PyQt6 btw).

I've tried things like QT Designer that can help you with drag n drop programming but I find it harder than coding directly on PyCharm...

Comment: That would depend entirely on the GUI toolkit you're using. If you're using PyQt/PySide, you can use QT Designer too.

Comment: as I said, I've tried QT Designer but I don't like the way it calls functions and I have how chaotic it is. the question was about other ways to do that (btw I'm using PyQt6)